# Applying function with multiple arguments to create a new pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Data'])
# input some random data into df

test_log = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Data'])

def test_func(date, data):
    if data > 2:
        data = data * 2 
        d = {'Date':date, 'data':data}
        return d


df.apply(lambda x: test_func(x['Date'],x['Data']), axis=1)
```

first of all this doesn't return a series of dictionaries `d`. When the function (`test_func`) used in `apply` returns a single value, a series is returned from the apply method, however when you return a dictionary from the function 'test_func' the df.apply method replaces the values in df with the returned values.

I want to run `test_func` on every line in `df`, then when `test_func` returns something it appends `test_log` with the values ie

`test_log = test_log.append(d, ignore_index=True)`

where `d` is dictionary returned by `test_func`

EDIT:

It returns a DataFrame when do:

```
def test_func(date, data):
    if data > 2:
        data = data * 2 
        d = {'Date':date, 'data':data}
        return pd.Series(d)
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: This is, the function in my actual code is much more complex, this is essentially the simplest process

Comment: If you provide a reproducible problem and desired final result, you will get a quick solution. Else, we have to read between the lines and figure out what you are trying to achieve. And that is not in the best interest of time for both the parties.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing without `apply`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['Date'] = pd.date_range('01/01/2010', periods=5)
>>> df['Data'] = np.arange(0,5,1)
>>> df
        Date  Data
0 2010-01-01     0
1 2010-01-02     1
2 2010-01-03     2
3 2010-01-04     3
4 2010-01-05     4

>>> test_log = df.loc[df.Data > 2]
>>> test_log.Data = test_log.Data * 2
>>> test_log
        Date  Data
3 2010-01-04     6
4 2010-01-05     8
```

Comment: Hi my function is more complex I have reposted here with more details, care to have a look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984807/how-to-run-a-function-on-each-row-in-dataframe-and-append-the-result-to-a-new-da