# How to run a function on each row in DataFrame and append the result to a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

NB My code runs if copied

I wrote a simple script to backtest cryptocurrencies using the poloniex API.

First I request the data from the API and turn it into a dataframe `data`.

Then I take the data I want and make new df called `df`

A function `trade` must then be run on each line in `df`, simple put if the price is above the rolling mean it buys and sells if below, this data is then saved in `log`.

I am having trouble applying this function on each row in `df`.

I had great success using the line `log = df.apply(lambda x: trade(x['date'], x['close'], x['MA']), axis=1)` BUT surprising it works when BTC_ETH is used in the API call and not for others ie BTC_FCT or BTC_DOGE despite the data being identical in form. Using ETH results in the creation of DataFrame (which is what i want) DOGE and FCT creates a Series

First question, how can I run my `trade` function on each row and create a new df `log` with the results

Bonus question, even though the data types are the same why does it work for ETH but not for DOGE/FCT ?

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

API = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_FCT&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=86400'
data = pd.read_json(API)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'date','close','MA'})

df.MA = pd.rolling_mean(data.close, 30)
df.close = data.close
df.date = data.date

df = df.truncate(before=29)

def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')

log = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'type', 'profit', 'port_value'])
port = {'coin': 0, 'BTC':1}

def trade(date, close, MA):

    if MA < close and port['coin'] == 0 :

        coins_bought = port['BTC']/MA

        port['BTC'] = 0
        port['coin'] = coins_bought

        d = {'Date':date, 'type':'buy', 'coin_value': port['coin'], 'btc_value':port['BTC']}
        return pd.Series(d) 

    elif MA > close and port['BTC'] == 0 :

        coins_sold = port['coin']*MA

        port['coin'] = 0
        port['BTC'] = coins_sold

        d = {'Date':date, 'type':'sell', 'coin_value': port['coin'], 'btc_value':port['BTC']}
        print()
        return pd.Series(d) 

log = df.apply(lambda x: trade(x['date'], x['close'], x['MA']), axis=1)

log = log.dropna()

print_full(log)
```

EDIT:

I solved the problem, I fixed it by appending the dicts to list and then using the df.from_dict() method to create the log dataframe, my code just to clarify.

```
def trade(date, close, MA):#, port):
    #d = {'Data': close}
    #test_log = test_log.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    if MA < close and port['coin'] == 0 :

        coins_bought = port['BTC']/MA

        port['BTC'] = 0
        port['coin'] = coins_bought

        d = {'Date':date, 'type':'buy', 'coin_value': port['coin'], 'btc_value':port['BTC']}
        data_list.append(d)

        #return pd.Series(d) 

    elif MA > close and port['BTC'] == 0 :

        coins_sold = port['coin']*MA

        port['coin'] = 0
        port['BTC'] = coins_sold

        d = {'Date':date, 'type':'sell', 'coin_value': port['coin'], 'btc_value':port['BTC']}

        data_list.append(d)

        #return pd.Series(d) 


df.apply(lambda x: trade(x['date'], x['close'], x['MA']), axis=1)

log = log.dropna()

for key,value in port.items():
    print(key, value )

log.from_dict(data_list)
```

Comment: According to [the documentation of `apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), using a function with side-effects (like yours) may lead to unexpected behaviour since it is called twice for the first row (see "Notes").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not always returning a value in `trade`, which is confusing Pandas. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

API = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_FCT&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=86400'
data = pd.read_json(API)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'date','close','MA'})

df.MA = pd.rolling_mean(data.close, 30)
df.close = data.close
df.date = data.date

df = df.truncate(before=29)

def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')

log = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'type', 'profit', 'port_value'])
port = {'coin': 0, 'BTC':1}

port = {'coin': 0, 'BTC':1}

def trade(date, close, MA):
    d = {'Date': date, 'type':'', 'coin_value': np.nan, 'btc_value': np.nan}

    if MA < close and port['coin'] == 0 :
        coins_bought = port['BTC']/MA
        port['BTC'] = 0
        port['coin'] = coins_bought
        d['type'] = 'buy'
        d['coin_value'] = port['coin']
        d['btc_value'] = port['BTC']

    elif MA > close and port['BTC'] == 0 :
        coins_sold = port['coin']*MA
        port['coin'] = 0
        port['BTC'] = coins_sold
        d['type'] = 'sell'
        d['coin_value'] = port['coin']
        d['btc_value'] = port['BTC']

    return pd.Series(d)

log = df.apply(lambda x: trade(x['date'], x['close'], x['MA']), axis=1)

log = log.dropna()

print_full(log)
```

However, as I mentioned in the comment, passing a function with side-effects to `apply` is not a good idea [according to the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), and in fact I think it may not produce the correct result in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, I actually just fixed the problem though, see post in 2mins for edits

Comment: @DavidHancock Well actually if you have solved it maybe better do not edit your original post and post your fix as an answer? (if it was something else)